# java jetty app connects one way to mysql in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, jetty

I am facing issue with my app it can connect to mysql in kubernetes when i ran it locally but ones i deploy it on pod it only can connect and executes first query but it never get response back and fails on timeout. I have tried running them in the same pod, various pods etc.

Comment: Please provide more information, your YAMLs with configuration, output for `kubectl get pods`, `kubectl get svc`.